# allocate array of char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

What is the difference between the following methods of declaration of char arrays and why the first one doesn't work?

```
 char *name[STR_SIZE];
 name = new char[10][STR_SIZE]; // this one gives "incompatible types in assignment of ‘char (*)[5]’ to ‘char* [5]’" error
```

```
char (*name)[STR_SIZE];
name = new char[10][STR_SIZE]; // this one works
```

Comment: I do not see any difference between the "methods of allocations". Both cases are allocated identically: "`new char[10][STR_SIZE];`". What's different is what the result of the allocation is assigned to, the two `name`s are completely different types. But you didn't ask about that, so you must understand that, so what exactly is your question, then?

Comment: Yes, you are right I should have asked about the difference between the declarations.

Comment: Well, one is an array of pointers to `char`s. The other is a pointer to an array of `char`s. That's it. That's the difference.

Comment: I changed the question. thanks!